# Program not working anymore if I rotate device due to gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

If I press a button and rotate my device afterwards my program isn't working anymore. I know, that the gesture recognizer is the problem but how can I fix it?
I add the gesture recognizer to my view and if the device rotates in landscape mode the gesture recognizer isn't working anymore. What could be done to solve that?
Here's some code:

```
// take a photo
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.fullScreenView.hidden = false
    self.recordButton.enabled = false
    self.takephoto.enabled = false
    self.recordButton.hidden = true
    self.takephoto.hidden = true

    session.startRunning()

    currentGesture = "Photo"

    // customize the quality level or bitrate of the output photo
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    // add the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the view and set the view in fullscreen
    fullScreenView.frame = view.bounds
    videoPreviewLayer.frame = fullScreenView.bounds
    fullScreenView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

    // add action to fullScreenView
    gestureFullScreenView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.takePhoto(_:)))
    self.fullScreenView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureFullScreenView)

    // add action to myView
    gestureView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.setFrontpage(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureView)

    if (preview == true) {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            // code for photo capture goes here...

            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                // process the image data (sampleBuffer) here to get an image file we can put in our view

                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)
                    var orientation: UIImageOrientation!


                    // image with the current orientation
                    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: (image?.CGImage)!, scale: 1, orientation: orientation)

                    // remove the gesture recognizer and stop the current session
                    self.fullScreenView.hidden = true
                    self.fullScreenView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(self.fullScreenView.removeGestureRecognizer)
                    self.session.stopRunning()

                    // save image to the library
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)

                    self.imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
                    self.imageViewBackground.image = newImage
                    self.imageViewBackground.tag = self.key

                    self.view.addSubview(self.imageViewBackground)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        preview = true
    }
}
```

and here I set the new frame:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    // if the device rotates, set these components into fullscreen
    fullScreenView.frame = view.bounds
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.bounds
    playerLayer?.frame = view.bounds
    imageViewBackground?.frame = view.bounds

    let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
    switch (orientation) {
        case .Portrait:
            videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
            countLabel.frame = CGRectMake(width * 0.4, -(width * 0.24), height/2, (width/2) * 1.25)
        case .LandscapeRight:
            videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeLeft
            countLabel.frame = CGRectMake((width * 0.72), -(width * 0.26), height/2, (width/2) * 1.25)
        case .LandscapeLeft:
            videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = .LandscapeRight
            countLabel.frame = CGRectMake((width * 0.72), -(width * 0.26), height/2, (width/2) * 1.25)
        case .PortraitUpsideDown:
            videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = .PortraitUpsideDown
            countLabel.frame = CGRectMake(width * 0.4, -(width * 0.24), height/2, (width/2) * 1.25)
        default:
            videoPreviewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = .Portrait
            countLabel.frame = CGRectMake(width * 0.4, -(width * 0.24), height/2, (width/2) * 1.25)

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show some code, otherwise we cant help

Comment: add codes, and also breakpoint to indicate at which particular code did it crash.